# playing HLS with chromecast from Android sender with v1.1 of https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Tags: android, chromecast

Yesterday everything seemed to work, but there is a chance I have changed something in my code, I just can't find out why it does not work anymore:

sender JAVA code:

```
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "My video");
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "My video sub title");
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, "Studio");
    mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xx/files/RMCipadPics/ipadtv.png")));
    mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xx/files/RMCipadPics/ipadtv.png")));//big image
    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
                    url)
                    .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL")
                    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                    .build();
    mVideoCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(StreamVideo.this, mediaInfo, 0, true);
```

using sample code for the receiver from Media Player Library (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) which I did not change except for some logging

the debug log (personal info removed) showed:

```
    Starting media application
we have protocol .m3u8 
Starting Media Player Library 
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. media_player.js:102
 [ 46.310s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 46.322s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 46.334s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 10:xx.xxxx.xxxx-54
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 46.346s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"10:xx.xxxx.xxxx-54","data":"{\"requestId\":2,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 46.191s] [cast.player.api.Player] error
 media_player.js:24
Fatal Error - 1 player.html:87
```

Comment: You may want to try a different HLS file to see if other files play.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. I will try one of the sample files http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/cast-media-server-samples/media.zip as well, but could not succeed yet. I will let you know.

Comment: Ok i tried HLS stream stream-1-109952 of the sample files. And it worked! I am sorry about the confusion. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: The trouble with my original hls source was that it didn't accept the mp3 part. Once I had set it to AAC with exactly the same bitrate and such it was good to go. Maybe other parameters with mp3 would have sufficed as well.